# Using list's elements in loops in r (example: setDT)

Tags: r, list, loops, data.table

I have multiple data frames and I want to perform the same action in all data frames, such, for example, transform all them into data.tables (this is just an example, I want to apply other functions too).

A simple example can be (df1=df2=df3, without loss of generality here)

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), var2 =c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2), var3 = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), var2 =c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2), var3 = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9))
df3 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), var2 =c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2), var3 = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9))
```

My approach was: (i) to create a list of the data frames (`list.df`), (ii) to create a list of how they should be called afterwards (`list.dt`) and (iii) to loop into those two lists:

list.df:

```
list.df<-vector('list',3)
for(j in 1:3){
  name <- paste('df',j,sep='')
  list.df[j] <- name
}
```

list.dt

```
list.dt<-vector('list',3)
for(j in 1:3){
  name <- paste('dt',j,sep='')
  list.dt[j] <- name
}
```

Loop (to make all data frames into data tables):

```
for(i in 1:3){
  name<-list.dt[i]
  assign(unlist(name), setDT(list.df[i]))
}
```

I am definitely doing something wrong as the result of this are three data tables with 1 variable, 1 observation (exactly the name `list.df[i]`).

I've tried to unlist the `list.df` thinking `r` would recognize that as an entire data frame and not only as a string:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  name<-list.dt[i]
  assign(unlist(name), setDT(unlist(list.df[i])))
}
```

But I get the error message:

```
Error in setDT(unlist(list.df[i])) : 
  Argument 'x' to 'setDT' should be a 'list', 'data.frame' or 'data.table'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), setDF)`? It's not clear what you want to achieve in the end.

Comment: I just want to transform all data.frames into data.tables, @Ananda Mahto. I have 37 of them in my original data base and to be able to loop it is important to save time. Both solutions presented below match exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put all the data into one dataframe. Then, if you want to iterate through dataframes, use dplyr::do or, preferably, other dplyr functions

```
library(dplyr)

data = 
  list(df1 = df2, df2 = df2, df3 = df3) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = "source") %>%
  group_by(source)
```

Comment: All the answers were very good: thank you! I am choosing this one because of the dplyr use.

Answer (score 1):

Change your last snippet to this:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  name <- list.dt[i]
  assign(unlist(name), setDT(get(list.df[[i]])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Alternative to using lists
list.df <- paste0("df", 1:3)

# For loop that works with the length of the input 'list'/vector
# Creates the 'dt' objects on the fly
for(i in seq_along(list.df)){
  assign(paste0("dt", i), setDT(get(list.df[i])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` (which deserve far more advertising):

**a)** If you need all your `data.frame`s converted to `data.table`s, then as was already suggested in the comments by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, iterate over your `data.frame`s with `setDT`

```
library(data.table)

lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), setDT)
# or, if you wish to type them one by one:
lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), setDT)

class(df1) # check if coercion took place
# [1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

**b)** If you need to bind your `data.frame`s by rows, then use `data.table::rbindlist`

```
data <- rbindlist(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), idcol = TRUE)
# or, if you wish to type them one by one:
data <- rbindlist(list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3), idcol = TRUE)
```

---

**Side note**: If you like chaining/piping with the [magrittr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/index.html) package (which you see almost always in combination with `dplyr` syntax), then it goes like:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
# for a)
mget(paste0("df", 1:3)) %>% lapply(setDT)
# for b)
data <- mget(paste0("df", 1:3)) %>% rbindlist(idcol = TRUE)
```